# C++ syntax, is this a lambda

Tags: c++, boost

I'm building a test automation solution for a test process. I ran into a link, but my C++ competency isn't that great. Could someone please explain the syntax below?

```
void read_loop(bp::async_pipe& p, mutable_buffer buf) {
    p.async_read_some(buf, [&p,buf](std::error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Received " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << "): '";
        std::cout.write(boost::asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(buf), n) << "'" << std::endl;
        if (!ec) read_loop(p, buf);
    });
}
```

[How to retrieve program output as soon as it printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816744/)

My solution needs to orchestrate binaries, that monitor data traffic. There are two main programs. One manages other programs, call it `B`. Program `A` just stores all data. The testing process should inspect the outputs and match some keywords. If matched, test passes. The high level solution should do I/O to all programs--manipulating states, and matching 'outputs'.

Comment: Yes there's a lambda expression in that statement.

Comment: What exactly about the code do you need explained? You have a function named `read_loop()` that is calling a method `async_read_some()` on a `bp::async_pipe` object. `async_read_some()` is being passed in a lambda as a callback function to be called after the read is finished. The lambda is outputting the data that was read, and if the read was successful then it calls `read_loop()` again to read more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a lambda looks like:

```
// This is the basics of a lambda expression.

[ /* Optional Capture Variables */ ]( /*Optional Parameters */ ) {
    /* Optional Code */
}
```

So the simplest lambda is:

```
[](){}
```

What are the different parts:

```
Capture Variables:   Variables from the current visible scope
                     that can be used by the lambda.
Parameters:          Just like a normal function, these are parameters
                     that are passed to the parameter when it is invoked.
Code:                This is the code that is executed and uses the
                     above mentioned variables when the lambda is invoked.
```

I think it is useful to consider what is likely (not specified) going on behind the senes. A Lamda is just syntactic sugar for a functor (a callabale object).

```
  int main()
  {
       int data = 12;
       // define the lambda.
       auto lambda = [&data](int val){
           std::cout << "Lambda: " << (val + data) << "\n";
       };

       lambda(2); // activate the lambda.
  }
```

This is semantically equivalent to the following:

```
  class CompilerGeneratedClassNameLambda
  {
      int& data;
      public:
          CompilerGeneratedClassNameLambda(int& data)
              : data(data)
          {}
          void operator()(int val) const {
              std::cout << "Lambda: " << (val + data) << "\n";
          }
  };
  int main()
  {
       int data = 12;
       CompilerGeneratedClassNameLambda lambda(data);

       lambda(2); // activate the lambda.
  }
```

In your code. This part is the lambda:

```
[&p,buf](std::error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Received " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << "): '";
        std::cout.write(boost::asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(buf), n) << "'" << std::endl;
        if (!ec) read_loop(p, buf);
    }
```